# strang "reduce" behavior in python2.7

Tags: python, reduce

I am writing a program to merge list of dictionary:

```
li = [{u'1234': [[1512734546591, 1512734552591]]}, {}, {}, {}]

reduce(lambda a, b: a.items() + b.items(), [l for l in li])
```

then it shows error

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

why ?

Comment: What is the point of `[l for l in li]`?

Comment: You're only merging the values, not the keys... http://treyhunner.com/2016/02/how-to-merge-dictionaries-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

Think about the result of `a.items() + b.items()` for the first iteration. What is the type of the result? The result is passed into the `lambda` as `a` on the next iteration.

It's a `list`. On the next iteration, `a` will be a `list` (the result of the previous `a.items() + b.items()`) and `b` will be a `dict`. At this point, `a.items()` is attempting to access the `items` attribute of a `list`, of which there is none.

Comment: Thank you very much! Good answer.
How can I merge a list of dict like: [dict, dict, dict] ?